# Converting from Index (integer label) to Date/time for a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to plot two exponential moving averages (EMA) along with the original data that has date/time units.

to produce the EMAs I use a function that returns an array of values based on the input data which I then use to create data frames of EMA with different periods using:

```
EMAl = pd.DataFrame()
EMAl['explow'] = ema(20) #array
```

The problem is that is produces the defult index units.

I believe I should be using  pd.to_datetime at some point but I'm unsure how to use it so that EMAs data/time units match those of the input data.

Here is how I load in the input data at the start.

```
tesla_df = yf.download('TSLA', 
                      start='2019-08-01', 
                      end='2020-08-31', 
                      progress=False)
```

here is the input dataframe -

```
Date        Open        High        Low          Close       Adj Close  Volume                      
2019-07-31  243.000000  246.679993  236.649994  241.610001  241.610001  9178200
2019-08-01  242.649994  244.509995  231.770004  233.850006  233.850006  8259500
```

I am unable keep the date column for a given time interval in the EMA dataframe which end up looking like this:

```
    exphigh
0   233.774002
1   233.656001
2   235.204002
3   235.139333
4   233.096220
```

When i try to plot the following

```
plt.figure(figsize=(22.5, 9.5))
tesla_df['Close'].plot(title="TSLA's stock price")
plt.plot(EMAl['explow'])
```

i get the following error message
'view limit minimum -36883.200000000004 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units'

Comment: It is unclear what is your issue. Post what your code does and an example of expected ouptut.

Comment: I've added some more information to the post. Hopefully, that'll make things clearer

Comment: Which line is raising the error ?
It looks like you have some negative value in a column interpreted as date for plotting.
All date values should be positive.

Comment: The error occurs because of the difference in units between the two data sets im trying to plot. I am stuck on how to convert the units of the new data set so that they match the original and can be plotted together.